# Number of objects of binary file

Tags: c++

I am saving array of pointers to binary file like this :

```
    int size=20;
    Car* p = new Car[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        p[i]=TimestampWithDescription("myname");
    }
    fstream file("shop.bin",ios::binary);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p),size*sizeof(Car));
    }

    file.close();
```

Now if I want to read all the objects from the same file ,but I don't know how many there are ,how can I find their number?

Comment: May I ask why save pointers to a file? They're rendered useless when your program ends.

Comment: You want [serialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization)

Comment: "but I don't know how many there are ,how can I find their number" Have you considered writing that number first?

Comment: @AndyG It's not writing pointers, but "bytes" (`char`s) pointed by `p`. It fails at it, since for each element of the array, it writes `size` elements to the file, instead of just the current one

Comment: Let's say you fixed your writing code. You have 2 alternatives while reading  -check file size and divide it by struct size to determine number of structs written. Or - better and preferable - use vector to store the data read (using push_back) It will grow as needed - at the end you can check vector size to see how many structs were actually read